# how to speed you php site?

Tags: mysql, php, google, performance

Hello Google begans to rank sites with the speed each site loads.

So how can i increase the speed of a php mysql site ? I am already Gzip compression

Answer (score 1):

Use memcache(d) to cache the result of common queries, then look up results against memcache first, it's far quicker than making repeated lookups to a database.

You'll need to rewrite some of your logic to have a "if value is not in memcache, then do the query, and store the data in the cache system" kind of algorithm.

Also consider using a [reverse proxy](http://varnish-cache.org/) to cache generated pages, fragments and images.  Load images and media from a seperate cookie-less domain, from a server running something that can serve faster than apache.  Nginx and lighttpd are good options for media servers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options... caching PHP pages is a good way to give most people a good experience.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators

Is this a site written from scratch, or something like Wordpress, Joomla, etc?  If you're running a CMS then there's very specific advice to give based on platform.

Answer (score 0):

Use [varnish](http://varnish-cache.org/) and [apc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php).